# smartsheet api exact match during searching

Tags: smartsheet-api

i have a node.js script that uses the smartsheet library function. Search works except it is not returning an exact match instead even if the search string has a few characters that match the smartsheet, all those rows are returned. How can you do a search with exact match ?

```
var options = {
    sheetId: xxxxxxxxxxx,
    queryParameters: {
    query: <string to search>
    }
};

// Search sheet.
smartsheet.search.searchSheet(options)
    .then(function (data) {
     console.log(data);
}
```

so if i search with 'test' as the search string its returning results where 1 or more characters with in 'test' like 'tes' is a match, it returns those rows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Smartsheet accepts partial matches - both in the UI as well as via the API.
To restrict to an exact match, enclose the search term in double quotes (").

Using the REST API, you can try: `https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/search/sheets/xxxxxxxxx?query=%22test%22`

Or in node:

```
var options = {
    sheetId: xxxxxxxxxxxx,
    queryParameters: {
        query: '"test"'
    }
};

// Search sheet.
smartsheet.search.searchSheet(options)
    .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

This is mentioned in the article https://help.smartsheet.com/articles/522231-searching-in-smartsheet#items